# Why firebase serve command show "Cannot GET /" ? firebase+nuxt+express

Tags: firebase, express, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I want to create SSR app with Nuxt.js & deploy it to firebase.

I tried `firebase serve` to run firebase locally and success.
So, I accessed specified URL(http://localhost:5001/foo/foo/widgets) in my Browser,
But showed  only `Cannot GET /` on Browser.

**And Browser(Chrome) devtool & Terminal don't show error logs.**

I can't understand why occurred `Cannot GET /`

Where can I check this errors?

Why `Cannot GET /`?

Please help me.

---

project_root/functions/lib/index.js

```php
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

process.env.DEBUG = "nuxt:*";

import * as express from "express";
const app = express();

const { Nuxt } = require("nuxt");

const config = {
  dev: false,
  ssr: true,
  ssrLog: true,
  buildDir: "nuxt",
  build: {
    publicPath: "/"
  }
};

const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);
app.use(nuxt.render);
exports.widgets = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```